# Drawing in a static location when using a camara transform

Tags: xna, monogame

I'm using a matrix transform to move a 2d camera in Monogame, and I was wondering: How, if I initiated my spritebatch with a matrix transform, can I draw something in a static (non-moving) position? For example, I want to put debugging variables in the corner of the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw the images or text with static location in an other spritebatch.Begin, which doesn't have a matrix transform.